# Disable the dates from current date to one week range in <input type="date">

Tags: php, html, input

I have a question to ask. How do you disable all the dates from the current date to 6 days? In short disabling the **one week** including the **present** in the

```
<input type="date">
```

calendar selection, anyone?

Comment: `<input type="date">` has minimal support - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility Suggest you take a look at jQuery or a similar library for a full-featured date control that works across most browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `min` attribute for date input. Use [`date`](http://php.net/date) function to set the min date:

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="<?=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 days')) ?>">
```

This disables date less than 6 days:

[image]

Comment: @RyuumiAiko Glad that it helped.